# How to cycle through an array of Audio objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, audio

I've recently started learning Javascript, and I'm working on my first web-embedded game, which is a musical puzzle game that uses the basic principals of twelve-tone serialist music.  My game is mostly done, and [you can find it here](http://jeremyseanbell.com/games/).  But I'm having trouble with audio.  I did manage to get it to play a sound when the user solves the puzzle, but I can't get it to actually play through the notes that appear on the game board.

Here's what I did: I created an array of 12 Audio objects, which contains every note from C to B.  Then I created a method called "playToneRow()" which plays through them all, with the order determined by the numeric array ToneRow.notes[].  Here's the code:

```
this.playToneRow = function()
{
    for (var i in this.notes)
    {
        noteSound[this.notes[i]].play();
    }
};
```

But this method only plays the last note of the tone row.  Now I should mention that my knowledge of Javascript has been cobbled together from various tutorials I've found online, and I'm fairly certain that there are significant gaps in my admittedly rudimentary coding skills.  But I figured that the problem was that I wasn't putting any space in between the sounds, so it was trying to play them all at once, but it didn't have enough channels so it only played the last one.  So then I tried this:

```
this.playToneRow = function()
{
    var x = 0;
    for (var i in this.notes)
    {
        x = this.notes[i];
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            noteSound[x].play();
        }, 700);
    }
};
```

Now I'm really not sure if I'm using setTimeout() properly, but I'm guessing not, because once again, it only played the last note.  I know that all 12 wav files are getting loaded, because if I change the tone row, it will play a different note.  So it does have access to all the audio files; it's just a matter of getting it to play them all (and in the right order).

Thanks!

Comment: Where is `noteSound` defined and how is it populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for` won't really care about your `setTimeout`, try:

```
this.playToneRow = function()
{
    var x = 0,
        length = 0,
        j = 0;
    for (var i in this.notes)
    {
        length += 1;
    }

    function runIteration () {
        x = this.notes[j];

        setTimeout(function()
        {
            noteSound[x].play();
        }, 700);

        if (j === length) return;

        j += 1;

        setTimeout(runIteration, 700);

    }

    runIteration();

};
```

Hopefully that does it. I've taken a look at your [code](http://jeremyseanbell.com/games/12tone.js) but its a bit complex so I wasn't able to determine if `this.notes` was an object or an array

Comment: Thanks vihan1086, your code was extremely helpful!  I made a couple small changes to it, and now it works like a charm.  `this.notes` is an array, so I was able to just use `this.notes.length`. Also, the `runIteration()` function didn't seem to have access to `this.notes`, so I added the line `var myArray = this.notes;` before defining `runIteration()`, and then I just substituted `myArray[j]` for `this.notes[j]`.  That did it! Thanks again!

Comment: @Explodey No problem :)   If this helped you, you can click the check mark next to my answer

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/kgvgcsg3/14/

```
var notes = [{'0':'tone1'},{'1':'tone2'}]

var playToneRow = function(i)
{
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            //notes[i].play(); goes here
            console.log(notes[i])
            if (i < notes.length-1){
                i++;
                playToneRow(i)
            }
        }, 700);
};

playToneRow(0)
```